# What is my middle name?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

I forgot my middle name, and I only wrote 3 things down to remember. I imagine they made more sense to me then.

> Enjoyed with baseball
>
> This vehicle isn't small
>
> Oh I wish...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be

> Ferdinand

because

> that was [Oscar Mayer's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_F._Mayer) middle name.
>
>  Oscar Mayer wieners are enjoyed with baseball.
>
>  This is not a small vehicle:
>  [image]
>
>  "[Oh I wish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNddW2xmZp8) I were an Oscar Mayer wiener..."

Comment: Wow, that makes absolutely no sense to me having not grown up in the US, but it seems to fit perfectly when I google it

Comment: Another of our great contributions to world culture!  (The song is very catchy, be warned...)

Comment: @bg6471 Im Canadian :D